# How to implement role based permissions in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a MERN application with different features. Lots of roles and features accordingly .I want to display specific data, nav options and divs to specific roles and hide those from others. Please remember I don't want to hide the whole component, but just a part of the components. I have secured the backend already but not sure how to stop displaying specific components.Where should I save roles(user info) so that I don't have to call API again and again.

Like here you can see how i am calling api to get user info.

```
try{
  const data=await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/role",
    _id,
    config
  );

  if(data.role=="admin"){
    delete DRoutes[0].children[0].children[2];
    console.log(DRoutes[0].children[0].children[2]);
  }
}
```

i dont want to repeat this process (calling api ) everytime i need user info.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the classic use cases for [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You have a context provider that has information about the currently logged-in user and is updated by (probably) the main application component. Then throughout the rest of the components, the ones that need to know about the user would be context consumers. See the documentation for examples, but here's a sketch:

```js
const { useState, useContext } = React;

const UserContext = React.createContext(
    null // No user is logged in yet
);

const PlainComponent = () => {
    return <div className="boxed">This component doesn't care about the user context</div>;
};

const UserAwareComponent = () => {
    const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
    const haveUser = userContext !== null;
    // You could use userContext?.hasNiftyAccess here, but sadly SO's
    // version of Babel is so out of date it doesn't know about
    // optional chaining
    const userHasNiftyAccess = userContext && userContext.hasNiftyAccess;
    return (
        <div className="boxed">
            This one does:
            {haveUser && <div>We have a user</div>}
            {!haveUser && <div>No user logged in</div>}
            {userHasNiftyAccess && <div>User with nifty access is logged in</div>}
        </div>
    );
};

const BlockCheckbox = ({ text, checked, update, disabled = false }) => {
    const onClick =
        update &&
        (({ currentTarget: { checked } }) => {
            update(checked);
        });
    return (
        <div>
            <label>
                {text}
                <input type="checkbox" disabled={disabled} checked={checked} onClick={onClick} />
            </label>
        </div>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    const [userLoggedIn, setUserLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [userHasNiftyAccess, setUserHasNiftyAccess] = useState(false);
    const userContext = userLoggedIn ? (userHasNiftyAccess ? { hasNiftyAccess: true } : {}) : null;
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={userContext}>
            <BlockCheckbox text="User Logged In?" value={userLoggedIn} update={setUserLoggedIn} />
            <BlockCheckbox
                text="User Has Nifty Access?"
                value={userHasNiftyAccess}
                update={setUserHasNiftyAccess}
                disabled={!userLoggedIn}
            />
            <hr />
            <PlainComponent />
            <UserAwareComponent />
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.boxed {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```